# flutter app crashes on adding stripe payment

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I have integrated stripe payments to add stripe card in my app. When I enter the card details and press save the app crashes and it does not add any cards.

This is the error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field type of type Ljava/lang/String; in class Lcom/stripe/android/model/PaymentMethod; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.stripe.android.model.PaymentMethod' appears in /data/app/com.myapp.app-R-dj9ia4P1t8S6GZZ0ApgA==/base.apk!classes3.dex)
```

Comment: This seems like something you should open an issue on the Stripe package's github page.

Comment: Hello @ajay131 did is your issue resolved ?

Comment: @Mitul no. I created my own credit card widget and called the Stripe API manually.

Comment: Thank you @ajay131 I am planning same

Comment: @ajay131 Did your issue resolved? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @AyeshaIftikhar no. I used the credit_card package of flutter. Then I wrote my custom code using firebase cloud functions. I can share the code if you want.

Comment: @ajay131 it would be so generous of you if you share that code with me.